# How to split the relation acording to diffrent values of a column in pig

Tags: hadoop, relational-database, apache-pig, bigdata

if suppose i am having employee relation whose schema is like name, age, location,salary,department..now i want to split this relation according to different values of a column.

Like all the employees working in New York will be in one relation, all the employees working in London will be in one relation and so on..

Answer (score 0):

Use [SPLIT](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#SPLIT).Assuming your file is Employee.txt and the fields are tab delimited.

```
A = LOAD 'Employee.txt' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (name:chararray, age:int, location:chararray, salary:double, department:chararray);
SPLIT A INTO X IF location == 'New York', Y IF location == 'London';
DUMP X;
DUMP Y;
```

Comment: thank you for your reply.. but i had this in my mind before..
but the thing is that there are many different values in location column.. s it will be a very long process to sit and split the relation.. isn't there any other way?